# How to get through with slider in mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

[image]

I am working in MVC 2.0. Now I got a requirement regarding the Slider in the MVC. I have attached a image file below. How to implement this in MVC? How to get started with this? Is there any jQuery for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice [jquery slider plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/) you may take a look at. And here's [another one](http://blog.egorkhmelev.com/2009/11/jquery-slider-safari-style/).